What happens after a Photon pass-es through an element without causing any ElectronTransition? e.g. A Cube of Scanadium
Assuming:-

No ElectronTransition ==> Photon passes through the atom. [right?]

Longer Version In Words:- If a Photon doesn't have enough energy / has more energy than to trigger a ElectronTransition --> Then it isbelieved / usually told to be "Passing Through The Atom".



https://atomic-spectra.net/sp_hires.png

In Words:- Lots of elements (even METALs) have big chunks in their spectrum which doesn't cause ElectronTransition --> REF:-




The Question:-
What happens after a Photon pass-es through an element without causing any ElectronTransition? What does it really mean to pass through? (Specially when it was a solid/liquid that the photon didn't cause ElectronTransition to? Will that be different from what is taught in High School about a SingleATOM & that it passes through?)

e.g. What about a Cube/Chunk of Scanadium? FOR-REF:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandium#/media/File:Scandium_sublimed_dendritic_and_1cm3_cube.jpg
What if we shine the Photons on it that doesn't cause ElectronTransition to it? Shouldn't Scanadium let those Photons pass-through in straight line & appear Transparent?

I have read these:-

[Basic Good Explainer] How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?
Why do lines in atomic spectra have thickness? (Bohr's Model)
Line broadening: What is actually broadened?
What "happens" to the energy of a photon after it is absorbed? [Kind of talks about what I was asking for... but I wanna know the entire story about it ☺️]
What happens to photons after they hit objects?
What happens after a photon is absorbed by an electron
What determines if a lamp produces emission or blackbody spectra?

Want to watch but feels really hard

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4
Is there an actual proof for the energy-time Uncertainty Principle?
Atomic natural line width [What's a Eisenstate? Hamiltonian?]
What is the meaning of natural line broadening? [‍]


Scandium is a metal, so photons in the visible will be absorbed pretty quickly unless the scandium is a very thin film.

Yeup yeup, I am asking for, why does that happen. You can suggest me books / articles too . Cz, my High School books doesn't talk about that/these stuffs. Thank you @JonCuster

Because solid metals are not atomic gases. Solid metals have lots of free electrons with plenty of empty states in a continuum so there are no issues absorbing IR to near-UV photons.

You are saying like, basically anything that has FreeElectrons.... can just "ABSORB" / cause electronTransitions (in empty states in a continuum).... from the entire visible spectrum.... every single possible wavelength/frequency + more from IR & near-UV photons? ‍️   That's interesting. Can you share some relevant courses/books or at least field of study's name, sir?  Thank you

@REYNEP The relevant field is solid-state physics.

Didn't you already ask this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/815549/what-exactly-happens-to-the-unabsorbed-photons

@hft, not quite the same question. & the details in the question got confusing. I would need to completely change 80% of the structure of that question to turn it into what I am asking here..... Compare the two questions, This one is far more simpler .

Thank you @d_b.  I hope someone also writes up a summary of the basic concepts related to my question from Solid-State Physics & posts a answer here. Till then I will grab some books about that & study in my free time about it.

Here is a link to a solid state physics textbook: https://www.amazon.com/Solid-State-Physics-Neil-Ashcroft/dp/0030839939

Thank you for the book suggestion @hft  really appreciate it.

@hft - not a solid state textbook, the solid state textbook… I’ve treasured and referenced my copy for 40 years or more.

Okay okay, I will start reading it from today. --> For now I've found a good enough explanation for Solid State Photon/Quantum interactions from this thread over on reddit:- https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/gd7rs/how_does_reflection_work_in_an_atomic_level/

Photons pass through glass all the time without causing a transition.
Metals are different. Even though they don't promote a bound electron from one orbital to another, they do interact with photons. Metals contain electrons in states that are not attached to a single atom. These electrons can move within the metal.
In a simple classical description, light is an oscillating electromagnetic field. The field causes electrons to vibrate. The vibration absorbs the incoming light. Accelerated electrons radiate. This is the reflected beam.
